# Adjective beginning with 'c' that describes an institution that sacrifices individuality for conformity

Tags: synonyms

I'm struggling to remember the word, going through a bout of lethologica I guess. If someone can help me that would me great. I believe I first heard the word being used by William F. Buckley, if that's to any help. Perhaps, the word begins with 'Ch'- although I can't suggest that with certitude, It might come in handy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "**collectivist**" is the adjective you are looking for. Buckley frequently decried what he referred to as "collectivism" on American campuses and elsewhere as the enemy of individualism.  (See, *e.g.* one of his best known works *God and Man at Yale*.)

When Buckley used the term (especially in the 1950s and 1960s) he implicitly or explicitly evoked the collectivist ideology of the soviet union.  That is still the first definition in the online Miriam Webster ("a political or economic theory advocating collective control especially over production and distribution
also: a system marked by such control").  The second definition is "emphasis on collective rather than individual action or identity." Definition [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collectivism).